# how to run cordova application as a background service without any foreground notification

Tags: java, android, cordova, service, notifications

I am using

```
katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications
```

and

```
katzer/backgroundservice
```

But background service is using Foreground Notification and when my application goes in background and it receives any request from server it is producing a notification **which clashes with the foreground Notification** and my service stopped working.

i am using the following code for notification but LED is not showing any color.

```
window.plugin.notification.local.add({ led: 'A0FF05' });
```

also when my application goes on pause the background service is starting with huge **error**

```
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572): Activity com.example.test.CordovaApp has leaked ServiceConnection de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background.BackgroundMode$1@426a9df8 that was originally bound here
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.example.test.CordovaApp has leaked ServiceConnection de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background.BackgroundMode$1@426a9df8 that was originally bound here
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:965)
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:859)
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1344)
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1336)
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:401)
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background.BackgroundMode.startService(BackgroundMode.java:241)
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background.BackgroundMode.onDestroy(BackgroundMode.java:154)
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.onDestroy(PluginManager.java:255)
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.handleDestroy(CordovaWebView.java:794)
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.onDestroy(CordovaActivity.java:649)
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5370)
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1113)
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3301)
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3332)
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:140)
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
12-23 13:54:08.180: E/ActivityThread(15572):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please tell me the solution for running application as a background service but without any foreground service or notification